# Variables in python regex? Print statements in airflow?

Tags: python, regex, airflow

I am working on a simple program to see if a file "test-2018-06-04-1358.txt" exists in a directory using airflow. I have two issues.

A) I want to use the variable datestr in my regex. Not sure how to do that.

B) Secondly, Where does my print(filename) show up in airflow UI? I checked my view log but nothing showed up.

```
def checksFile():   
        d = datetime.today()-timedelta(days=1)
        datestr = '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(d)
        for filename in os.listdir('/mnt/volume/home/aabraham/'):
            match = re.search('(test)-(2018-06-04)-(\d+)(\.txt)', filename)
            print(filename)
        if not match:
            raise AirflowException("File not Found")
```

Comment: If you find you are not getting the answers you want, this could be a good question to split into 2.  1 for the regex, and 1 for airflow.  I could see a regex pro not wanting to answer since they don't know airflow or vice versa.

Comment: will keep in mind, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `print` in the same fashion as in the console.

To see logging entries in the `Log` page use `logging.info`. Maybe you need to `import logging`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the regex question, just add the strings together:

```
match = re.search('(test)-(' + datestr + ')-(\d+)(\.txt)', filename)
```

This will only work if `datestr` doesn't contain any regex literals.

Comment: couldn't  also mark this as correct, but this works. thank you!

Comment: @friendly1358 you can upvote both answer though, and that would help the people who answered :)

Comment: @sniperd Can he? He doesn't have 15 rep.

Comment: @MegaIng ooopps!  You are right.  I'll do it by proxy then :)